# How Teleport App integrates Uber API?

Tags: web, uber-api

First of all UberCENTRAL seems like not available in my country. I want to give my users free Uber rides to my stores directly from my website (web app, not native app), and there are 2 options:

- UberCENTRAL (not available for me)
- Teleport APP
  (http://teleportapp.co/ ,they use Uber API and it's +2$ per ride)

But I was reading the UberAPI and I can't find how to pay for my users rides. It seems like the API just works to make users pays for their rides, but I can't set up my code to do what Teleport APP does. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Uber Deeplinks to apply a promotional code for users who come straight from your app. The [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-promotions/introduction#apply-a-promotion-code-with-a-deep-link) describes how to accomlish that, for instance:

```
uber://?action=applyPromo&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&promo=<PROMO_CODE>
```

You can get promo codes through [UberEVENTS](https://www.uber.com/events).